# -1.#IND00 output for certain input values

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that will take `x` as input and give `cos(x)` as output, using maclaurin's series.I'm using a while loop until the difference of two consecutive results is less then `0.001`. I'm using `double` type to accomodate larger values.
the code works when `x` is in range `[-2,2]`, but if `x` is greater or less than this range the ouput is `-1.#IND00`. Why is it happening? is the output value out of range ? how can i fix this ??

my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

double abs(double a);
double power(double p, int q);
int fact(int a);

int main()
{
    int i=1,j=2*i;
    double x,s=1.0,p,l=0.001;
    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    p = s+ power(-1,i) * power(x,j) / fact(j);
    while (abs(p-s)>l){
        i++; j=2*i;
        s=p;
        p = s+ power(-1,i) * power(x,j) / fact(j);
    }
    printf("cos(%f) = %f", x,p);
    return 0;
}

double abs(double a)
{
    if (a>=0) return a;
    else return (-a);
}

double power(double p, int q)
{
    int i;
    double a=1.0;
    for (i=0; i<q; i++){
        a=a*p;
    }
    return a;   
}

int fact(int a)
{
    int i,p=1;
    if (a==0 || a==1) return 1;
    else
        while (a!=1){
            p=p*a;
            a--;
        }
        return p;
}
```

Comment: What inputs are making this fail?

Comment: Should scanf("%f", &x); be scanf("%lf", &x);?

Comment: if i give the input x=3, the output is "-1.#IND00". and yes, i used "%lf", gives the same output

Answer (score 0):

update your `scanf` function to

```
scanf("%lf", &x);
```

Also you need to check `pow` and `fact`, these functions could overflow. Especially, `fact` which only use `int`.

Comment: thanks, editing mistake. i actually used %lf. the problem is still there

Comment: does maclaurin's series converge at x = 3?

Comment: Uh, I think you need to check `fact`, because it may overflow for large number of int.

Answer (score 0):

As a larger `|x|` is use, more terms are needed and `fact()` overflows and strange results follow.  Use `double`.

```
// int fact(int a)
double myfact(double p, int q) {
  int i;
  double a = 1.0;
  for (i=0; i<q; i++){
    a=a*p;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Eventually with values somewhere larger `|x|` > 30, other limitations kick in using this method.  The limitation is due to precision and not range.  For large values a significantly different algorithm should be used.

---

Potential conflict between `int abs(int j)` in `<stdlib.h>`.  The prototyped *may* be found via `stdio.h` and conflicts with OP `double abs(double a)`.  In any case, `abs()` is a standard library function and OP should avoid that function name.  Also recommend renaming `power()`.

```
// double abs(double a)
double myabs(double a)
```